# What is wrong in this sql select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

Here is my select statement,

```
SELECT TOP 1
  EmpId, RemainingAdvance 
FROM SalaryDetails
WHERE EmpId IN (SELECT Emp_Id
                FROM Employee
                WHERE Desig_Id='27')
ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

When i executed `SELECT Emp_Id FROM Employee WHERE Desig_Id='27'` the results were

> Emp_Id
>    16
>    17

But when i execute my first statement it gives me result for only `16` but no output `17`...
I have records for both EmpId's in `SalaryDetails` Table.....

**EDIT:**

Removing TOP 1 from my query i got this,

```
SELECT EmpId, RemainingAdvance FROM SalaryDetails 
where EmpId in (select Emp_Id from Employee where Desig_Id='27')
               ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC
```

gave me

[image]

I want results for `EmpId 16,17` `ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC`... Because my now my `Desig_Id='27'` and i will change it with a variable `@CategoryId` ... So there may be 'n' number of employees based on `@CategoryId`

```
EmpId  RemainingAdvance
16                354.00
17                 0.00
```

Comment: @Peter I ll edit it for you...

Comment: Please try what @OMG Ponies has to say (using CTE, RANK). See if it helps you in terms of performance & readability.

Comment: Have you established why your query failed in the first place as to my way of thinking it *should* work. Provided there is a row in the SalaryDetails table for both EmpId's 16 and 17.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SD.EmpId, SD.RemainingAdvance 
FROM 
SalaryDetails SD INNER JOIN 
   (SELECT SD2.EmpID, MAX(SD2.CreatedDate) AS MAXDate 
   FROM SalaryDetails SD2 GROUP BY SD2.EmpID) AS SD2
ON SD.EmpID = SD2.EmpID
INNER JOIN Employee E
ON SD.EmpID = E.EmpID
WHERE E.Desig_Id = '27' AND SD.CreatedDate = SD2.MaxDate
```

Note: The query is written without trying it out.
I suppose, this is what you are looking for.

---

This variant also works (in at least one DBMS - namely IBM Informix Dynamic Server 11.50):

```
SELECT SD.EmpId, SD.RemainingAdvance 
  FROM SalaryDetails SD
       INNER JOIN 
       (SELECT SD2.EmpID, MAX(SD2.CreatedDate) AS MAXDate 
          FROM SalaryDetails SD2 GROUP BY SD2.EmpID) AS SD2
       ON SD.EmpID = SD2.EmpID AND SD.CreatedDate = SD2.MaxDate
       INNER JOIN Employee E
       ON SD.EmpID = E.EmpID
 WHERE E.Desig_Id = '27'
```

The compound join in the first ON clause might improve the performance of the query - but it is quite possible that the optimizer would hoist the 'AND SD.CreatedDate = SD2.MaxDate' condition anyway, meaning you wouldn't spot any difference even if you examined the two query plans.  I'm not quite sure of the best way to indent the table expressions after the main FROM clause.

*Edited by Jonathan Leffler - as requested by Shahkalpesh.*

Comment: Please try & see if the example by @OMG Ponies works as well. I think his solution is elegant & could also be better, performance wise. And, why not use the language feature that is available? you will learn a bit of new ways of doing things :)

Comment: +1: What I like about this answer is that it doesn't rely on analytic functions.  It would work on MySQL as well as Oracle too.

Comment: Does the performance improve at all if you move the 'AND SD.CreatedDate = SD2.MaxDate' clause up to the 'ON SD.EmpID = SD2.EmpID' clause.  Does the optimizer do that anyway?  (Given the sample data in my answer, your query as written and my suggested variant both produce the same answer as my query with the ghastly correlated sub-query.)

Comment: @Jonathan: Good point. Can you edit this post & include that as well? I am not sure of optimizer (because I am writing this inside SO textbox, no SQL editor at hand)

Answer (score 5):

`SELECT TOP 1` returns only one row.

You could try to use `SELECT TOP 10` instead.

**EDIT**:

You always get `16`, because it seems to have the higher `CreatedDate`, and you sort by that column descending.

Comment: @Peter I have to use TOP 1 only... I can get record for `empid=16`
but not for `empid=17`

Comment: @Pandiya: you will only get one row (the one for empid = 16) if you say 'TOP 1'.  If you mean 'top one for each different emp_id', you need a radically different (and more complex) query.

Comment: @Pandiya Chendur: I have edited my answer. Please provide more information in case I am missing something :)

Comment: If you have a legit reason for wanting TOP 1 in this case, you probably need to do some normalization.

Answer (score 5):

### SQL Server 2005+, Using CTE and ROW_NUMBER:

---

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT sd.empid,
           sd.remainingadvance,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.empid ORDER BY sd.createddate DESC) AS rank
      FROM SALARYDETAILS sd
      JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.emp_id = sd.empid
                     AND e.desig_id = '27')
SELECT s.empid,
       s.remainingadvance
  FROM summary s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

### SQL Server 2005+, Non-CTE Equivalent

---

```
SELECT s.empid,
       s.remainingadvance
  FROM (SELECT sd.empid,
               sd.remainingadvance,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.empid ORDER BY sd.createddate DESC) AS rank
          FROM SALARYDETAILS sd
          JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.emp_id = sd.empid
                         AND e.desig_id = '27') s
 WHERE s.rank = 1
```

Reference:

- [ROW_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: My answer is crude. I haven't used CTE & Rank related functions. But, I suppose your solution could be better (performance wise). Like I said, I wrote the query without trying it out. +1, even if it didn't work as OP expected (because of the way you introduced the new way of achieving results using enhancements to t-SQL)

Comment: On a side note, is there a term for such kind of functionality? same as vocabulary for design patterns?

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Nothing crude about your answer - using the latest in functionality isn't always the best.  They should both be tested and compared.  I'm sorry, but I don't understand what term/functionality you are referring to.

Comment: Just like there is "co-related subqueries", what would you call this kind of functionality (where you want to pick the contents of the row where the aggregated value is found)?

Answer (score 3):

This works, but the correlated sub-query is not efficient:

```
CREATE TABLE employee
(
    empid INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    desig_id CHAR(2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO employee VALUES(16, '27');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(17, '27');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(15, '13');
INSERT INTO employee VALUES(18, '9');

CREATE TABLE salarydetails
(
    empid INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES employee,
    createdate DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (empid, createdate),
    remainingAdvance DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (15, '2009-12-13', 1534.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (16, '2010-01-31', 3634.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (16, '2010-02-14', 2634.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (17, '2010-01-03', 5734.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (17, '2010-02-03', 4734.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (17, '2010-03-01', 3734.00);
INSERT INTO salarydetails VALUES (18, '2010-01-13', 5834.00);

SELECT s1.empid, s1.remainingAdvance
FROM SalaryDetails AS s1
WHERE s1.empid IN (SELECT e.empid FROM employee AS e WHERE e.desig_id = '27')
  AND s1.createdate = (SELECT MAX(s2.createdate)
                          FROM salarydetails AS s2
                         WHERE s2.empid = s1.empid);
```

Result:

```
EmpID       RemainingAdvance
   16                2634.00
   17                3734.00
```

Comment: @Jonathan: Feel free to comment on my answer, if you found that it isn't efficient. +1 for the efforts. I would like OP doing that for us, when posting the question :)

Comment: @Shahkalpesh: you were devising your answer while I was devising mine; I prefer your 'all join' notation, but decided to leave mine up for the time being.

Comment: Please go ahead & express your thoughts in SQL on my/your post. Even if the optimizer does this for us, it is better to have SQL clearly express the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Select Top 1 will select one top row. Lose the top 1 if you want to see all of them

Answer (score 0):

The statement performs as it is told you, but not as you intended to.

I guess you want to have the most recent SalaryDetails record for each Employee with a certain Desig_ID:

```
SELECT EmpId, RemainingAdvance
FROM SalaryDetails
WHERE CreatedDate IN
    (SELECT MAX(d.CreatedDate)
     FROM SalaryDetails d
     INNER JOIN Employee e ON d.EmpId = e.EmpId
     WHERE e.Desig_Id = '27'
     AND SalaryDetails.EmpId = d.EmpId
    )
```

Comment: Your interpretation of the question is correct; I think your answer is not, because if there are 30 employees who all got their salary details changed on the same day as someone with Desig_ID = '27', they will all be shown in the result set, even if their Desig_ID is not '27'.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler note the inner WHERE condition on inner and outer SalaryDetails.EmpId

Comment: yes - you're right.  My mistake.  When the superfluous close bracket is removed, your query produces the same result as the other working ones.  Correlated sub-queries are murderous...